# Aggregate tables vs real-time analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, real-time, analytics, data-warehouse

I've been researching different approaches to streaming data to a real-time dashboard. One way that I have done in the past is using a star schema/dimension and fact tables. This would be an implementation of aggregate tables. For example, the dashboard would contain multiple charts, one being the total sales for the day, total sales by product, total sales by manufacturer, etc. etc.

But what if this needed to be real-time?  What if the data needs to stream to these charts and do the analytical processing real-time?

I've been looking into solutions like Kinesis streams and Kafka, but I may be missing something obvious. For example, consider the following example. A company runs a website where they sell pies. The company has a backend dashboard where they keep track of all data and analytics related to sales, users, orders, etc.

1. Custom places order through website
2. The relational (mysql) database receives this new order
3. The charts and analytical data updates real-time on the backend, for example total sales for the day, or total sales for the year by user.

If the scenario is that this data needs to be streamed, what is the best approach to this? Aggregate tables seem like the obvious but it seems that would be periodic and not real-time. Kinesis/Kafka feels like it would fit somewhere in here. The other option would be something like Redshift but it's pretty pricey and still may not be the best way to address the issue and scale.

Here is an example of a chart that would need to be updated in real-time that could suffer by just doing place aggregate SQL queries when there are tons and tons of rows to parse.

[image]

Comment: Just to address the aggregate vs realtime issue: if you have some aspect of columnar technology (such as Redshift), there's less need for an aggregate as those kinds of queries can be done more quickly.

Comment: Are you sure that real-time updates are really needed for dashboard like that?.. Maybe you mean that numbers should be up-to-date at the time of rendering (as variant, dashboard can update widgets periodically - say, every minute - transparently for the end-user).

Comment: @VitaliyFedorchenko But even if it were a minute or 5, i'd still have the problem of having to aggregate or use a star schema, or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of "always up-to-date" reports like this (sales, users, orders etc) that don't need live updates with near-zero-latency streaming processing might be overkill, and ROLAP-like approach seems to be more optimal in meaning of efforts/result.

You mentioned Redshift, and if you already ready to mirror your data for analytics purposes and only problem is a price you can consider another free open-source alternatives that could be used for handling OLAP (aggregate) queries in the real-time (like Yandex ClickHouse, or maybe MongoDb in some cases).

A lot of depends on the dataset size; unless you have really big data that need to be aggregated (hundreds of GB) you can try to keep using mysql and use some tricks:

- use separate slave mysql server with high IOPS for analytics and replicate only tables needed to build your reports; possibly use another table engine, more suitable for analytical queries. Setup indexes specially for these queries, to avoid table full scan if you need to get numbers only for last weeks.
- pre-calculate metrics for previous periods (with materialized view-like approach) and refresh them on schedule (say, daily), and then combine pre-calculated aggregates with on-the-fly aggregates only for last period to get actual report data without need to scan whole facts table each time.
- use data visualization backend that can efficiently cache reports data in-memory to prevent SQL DB overload because of many similar queries (and if the same report or dashboard is displayed for 100 users SQL DB load will be the same as for 1). BTW, I develop solution like that (cannot adv it here as it is commercial product).

Comment: I went with an version of your first answer, using a replicated instance in memsql.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical trade-off for most the architects. Amazon Redshift offers exemplary read optimisations but AWS stack comes for a price. You may try using Cassandra, but it comes with its own set of challenges. When it comes to analytics, I **never** recommend going real time for the reasons elaborated below.

> **Doing analytics at real time is not desired, specially using MySQL**

The solution for above comes by seggregating transactional and analytical infra. This involves cost but will make sure you don't have to spend time in housekeeping once you scale. MySQL is a row based RDBMS mostly used for storing transactional data. Being row based, it optimises writes i.e. the writes are almost real time and thus, it compromises on reads. When I say this, I refer to a typical analytics dataset running into millions of records/day. If your dataset is not that voluminous, you might still be able to render a graph showing transactional status. But since you're referring to Kafka, I assume the dataset is very large.

> **A real-time dashboard with visualisations gives a bad customer experience**

Considering the above point, even if you go for a warehouse / a read optimised infra, you need to understand how the visualisations work. If 100 people access the dashboard at the same time, 100 connections will be made to the database, all fetching the same data, putting them in memory, applying calculations, parameters and filters defined in your dashboard, adjust the refined dataset in the visualisation and then render the dashboard. Till this time, the dashboard will simply freeze. *A poorly constructed query, inefficient use of indexes etc will further make the matter worse.*

> The above problems will amplify more and more with the increase in your dataset. Good practices to achieve what you need would be:

1. To have almost realtime (delay of 1hr, 30 mins, 15 mins etc) rather than an absolute real time system. This will help you to create a flat file with the data already fetched in the memory. Your dashboard will simply read this data and will be extremely fast in terms of responses to filters etc. Also, multiple connections to databases will be avoided.
2. Have a data structure, database/warehouse optimised for reads.

Answer (score 0):

For these types of operational analytics use-cases where the real-time nature of the data is critical, you're completely correct that most "traditional" methods can be quite clumsy, especially as your data size increases. A quick overview of your options:

#### Historical Approach (TLDR– Meh)

Up until about 5 years ago, the de facto way to do this looked something like

1. Set up a primary [OLTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing) database that will handle the data in its raw form and have stricter guarantees on performance or ACID properties. Usually this is something SQL-esque, i.e. MySQL, PostgreSQL.
2. Set up a secondary [OLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) database that is meant for serving offline (aka non user-facing) queries. This could also be a SQL-esque db but its schema would be drastically different because it stores the data in enriched form.
3. Set up some mechanism by which you can keep these 2 in sync. This pretty much boils down to either a) changing your application to always write to both databases and performing the necessary data enrichment or b) building a stand-alone application that reads from your OLTP database, performs the necessary transformations and enrichment and writes to your OLAP database
4. Plug your dashboard into your OLAP database which will have a schema and indexes optimized for the kind of queries you want.

Using your example about the pie store, the OLTP database would be used to store the purchases of all the pies and reference things like customer ids, billing information, delivery information, etc. In contrast, the OLAP database might just maintain a table with a schema

```
purchase_totals(day: Date, weekNumber: int, dayOfWeek: int, year: int, total: float)
```

While the `weekNumber`, `dayOfWeek`, and `year` and technically redundant **they make your queries faster!** With the proper indexes on these fields, your dashboard has turned into 5 simple (and fast!) aggregation queries with a group by and sum, and then the differences week-over-week or year-over-year can be computed on the client-side. As long as your dashboard refreshes every minute or so you have near-real-time data at your fingertips.

#### Current Approach (TLDR– Ok)

The recent trends in computing, database technologies, and data science/analytics have led to improvements to the above process, namely by replacing certain components of it. The changes include

1. Making the OLTP db, the OLAP db, or both a NoSQL database (Mongo usually being the most popular). The pro here is that you have a more flexible schema which won't break if something upstream changes (say, you start selling cakes in addition to pies).
2. Keeping the SQL db but shifting to cloud provider solution like AWS RDS or Google Cloud SQL. This fundamentally doesn't change anything about the architecture, but it does significantly reduce your operational burden.
3. Using hard-to-maintain [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) pipelines on top of streaming platforms like Kafka or AWS Kinesis to act as the middle layer between OLAP and OLTP.
4. Using dedicated tools for data cleaning and transformation as you plan out how to do your ETL
5. Using dedicated visualization tools on top of your OLAP db (think [Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/))
6. Using a pull-based approach for getting data out of your OLTP db or your application directly instead of waiting for it to eventually reach your OLAP db. This is helpful for online services because it actually gives you both the data you want AND confirmation that the service is alive and running well (because it just served your request for data). Systems like [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) are quite popular for this now.